# How to include node_module when building for iOS in ionic 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, typescript, ionic2, node-modules

im about to use an autosize module for automatic resize of a ion-textarea.

Module:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

I have installed it like the docs said and i testet it in the browser (ionic serve) and on my iPhone(ionic build ios => run with xcode).

Browser => the module does what it should and resizes the textarea perfectly.

Iphone => it does nothing

Question:
Do i have to specially include node_modules to let the "ionic build ios" command know that i need this module?

Would be really great if somebody can help me with this, i will get some :beer: for the guy who can help me on this.

Greetings Daniel

Here a Screencast of the working plugin in Browser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To have a plugin in your node_modules in ionic there are 2 things to do.

1) add it to your `package.json` <- this will generate the actual node_module folder

2) add it to your `config.xml` as a `<plugin>` (although I'm not sure since this was installed with `npm` maybe `package.json` will be enough